# How to solve the trouble with running javascript in asp.net app (WebForms) after postback?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have javascript, that scrolled floating block on my web page in asp.net app. After postback script doesn't work. How to solve the problem?

Comment: plz post ur source code...and explain clearly what issue u r facing..

Comment: Script is not required to answer my question. Script scroll div block on the page  like this http://www.magentawave.com/2013/02/simple-jquery-floating-block.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your java script function after postback

```
    Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "err_msg", "Your Function Name()");
```